# Flow default values type checking

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I've got a problem with Flow type checking when I assigns default values with `Object.assign`. Here is an example:

```
type ConfigIn = {
  someValue?: number,
};

type Config = ConfigIn & {
  someValue: number,
};

function test(config: ConfigIn): number {
  // here Flow will report an error:
  // Cannot assign `Object.assign(...)` to `myConfig` because 
  // undefined [1] is incompatible with number [2] in property `someValue`.:
  const myConfig: Config = Object.assign({}, {
    someValue: 1000,
  }, config);

  return otherFunction(myConfig.someValue);
}

function otherFunction(input: number): number {
  return 123;
}
```

Here is a link to the online example: [https://flow.org/try...](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AYVgHaQCWA5gJIGgC8oA3oqKAM6wC2WAagIbQCuWAPwAuUAT5sARlgBOAGkQBfANzJ02PIRKkamomUqgAZPUYt2XXgNHipshSuSQ+BAMYpihUCizMUAClctMlF8fQoCAEobCWkZUyYQUAALWRwAMTh4UHhiaGhQGSwMWBkUUG4qWRlS4TMk3EqCWHLuZmYyKgADAHlJACssdwA6No7SAn9h6ciu71hQLrY0MO056VduPmYcFwATLBICLD3QAG0ARgBdUGJmW7d2DG4PSWgcXJRksVjZc4AmG7EKgYGrYMpoRasDg8fhYLrDOpMIIEPygZarEJ6bS6PqDEZjTr+OiKOQJJjmGFWLCiC4ABgZCiYpNAKO0kVUZiKKD4MioLVSMnSLncnkmGOCpGG0MscI5SicIo8XgFsmFbmVk2BGD4KBidhk0R+BvJ3N5VAu-wAzKpFEA)

If I use `ConfigIn` type instead of `Config` everywhere I will get:

```
Cannot call `otherFunction` with `myConfig.someValue` bound to `input` 
because undefined [1] is incompatible with number [2].
```

Here is the link: [https://flow.org/try...](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AYVgHaQCWA5gJIGgC8oA3oqKAM6wC2WAagIbQCuWAPwAuUAT5sARlgBOAGkQBfANzJ02PIRKkamomUqgAZPUYt2XXgNHipshSuSQ+BAMYpihUCizMUAClctMlF8fQoCAEobCWkZUyYQUAALWRwAMTh4UHhiaGhQGSwMWBkUUG4qWRlS4TMk3EqCWHLuZmYyKgADAHlJACssdwA6No7SAn9h6ciu71hQLrY0MO056VduPmYcFwATLBICLD3QAG0ARgBdUGJmW7d2DG4PSWgcXJRksVjZc4AmG7EKgYGrYMpoRasDg8fhYLrDOpMIIEPygZarEJ6bSGWh9QYjMadfx0RRyBJMcwwqxYUQXAAMjIUTDJoBR2kiqjMRRQfBkVBaqRk6Rc7k8kwxwVIw2hljhnKUTlFHi8gtkIrcKsmwIwfBQMTsMmiP0NFJ5fKoF3+AGZVIogA)

What is a recommended way to solve this without using type `any` somewhere?

**BONUS**

What if my `ConfigIn` type has nested properties?

Example: [https://flow.org/try...](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmBJBUC8UDeAUFFAM5wC2EAagIYA2ArhAPwBcUCjFARhAE4AaYlDjAAFgLpMIHIiRLAIpYBy68BwkgF9C2gNyFCoSLESo0uAiIB0d+MnRYtZSjQbM13PkL2HCSIwIAMbAKIhQSioAFMHm6BwOFlgAlF4a-NYkcQgqUBQgSQlmjpZ4API8AFYQoTa0pKToCNH42oJZCuRU0p5QAIwADMMu7VA5Fin+JPwQwIz82GKS-ABiQaHhLQVFaDbLUh4QNlHAU3pGgSFhEQdrGzctKAhgjKqc3gJpHxmds-OLAYAJgAzIZtEA)

Solution: This can be fixed by using [Exact Object Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types) check this [https://flow.org/try...](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmBJBUC8UDeAPgFBRQDOcAthAGoCGANgK4QD8AXFAs1QEYQATgBpSUOMAAWQhiwhd8YssAjlgXHvyGiyAX2KFdAbmLFQkWIlRpcBMQDpH8ZOiw6K1Ok1YbeAkcTGpkjMCADGwCiIUCpqABRhVuhcztZYAJS+WoJ2ZIkIalBUIKnJli42eADyfABWEBH29OTk6Ahx+LrCuWQeNLI+UACMAAxj7l1Q+dbpJmKCEMDMgtgS0oIAYqERUe3FpWj2azLeEPaxwLOBwduR0cebt7txKAhgzOrcfkKZX9k9CyWK2GACYAMwmXRAA)

Comment: Can you remove optional property, and make it normal object property, `type ConfigIn = {
  someValue: number,
};` Doing this, will remove error, but i dont think this is what you want?
beacuse Your Config is dependent on Config, but Config contains an optional property, so whenever Object.assign will concat, it might be difficult to know the optional property.

Comment: `config.someValue` should be optional in other case there is no point in setting the default value with `Object.assign`. So this is not a solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on created issue [#6616](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6616) on facebook/flow repository, [wchargin suggested](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6616#issuecomment-406445348) avoiding intersection operators (`Type1 && Type2`) because they tends to break more often.

Instead it's possible with type-spread operator:

```
type ConfigIn = {
  someValue?: number,
};

type Config = {
  ...ConfigIn, // spread instead intersection
  someValue: number,
};

function test(config: ConfigIn): number {
  const myConfig: Config = Object.assign({}, {
    someValue: 1000,
  }, config);

  return otherFunction(myConfig.someValue);
}

function otherFunction(input: number): number {
  return 123;
}
```

Try on: [https://flow.org/try/..](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmBJBUC8UDeAUFFAM5wC2EAagIYA2ArhAPwBcUCjFARhAE4AaQgF8A3IUKhIsRKjS4CxKADo18ZOizCS5KnSYQOXXgOHjJSRggDGwFIijAIpYAAobc9Bw3ysASmNuPn4lEk8EVygKEF9vWU0FPAB5HgArCDsVWlJSdAQ3fBFBMJIyShoGZg4ARgAGBp0oYqgI+X8JZX4IYEZ+bDhgAAsBADFrOwcCmLi0FT1Kww7RSwn7R0GR-nHbdYKUBDBGYCDTfkDOYIFS7t7+qBqAJgBmCREgA).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I really don't like the necessity of making `input` an optional argument. It doesn't make any sense other than avoiding Flow error message. Of course, this might be the only solution, I will wait for a while before accepting that. Maybe there is some other option (I hope).

Comment: @jmarceli Yeah, me also, unfortunately Flow generally have reasons for being still in unstable phase. Based on my personal experience it leads to fairly too many errors with typing, eg like this bug. Maybe it is also worth to be recorded as issue on their GitHub.

Comment: @jmarceli I have updated the answer with suggestions from issue

Comment: Wow. Thanks, It seems to be working as I expected. The only thing left are nested properties. I've described this problem and solution in my question if you are interested.